# $L^{1,w}$-norm of the Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, harmonic-analysis

I'm trying to prove that, for any function $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we have that 
$$
 \|f\|_1
 \leq C \|Mf\|_{1,w}
$$
for some constant $C >0$, where $\|\cdotp\|_{1,w}$ denotes the weak 1-norm, 
$$
\|g\|_{1,w} = \sup_{t > 0} \ t \  |\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |g(x)|> t \rbrace |
$$
and $|A|$ is the measure of a set $A$.

So far, my argument goes as follows:

> If $Q_r$ denotes the cube of center zero and radius $r$, we can
>   clearly write  $$ \|f\|_1 = \sup_{r > 0} \int_{Q_r} |f| $$ Notice
>   that, if $f \neq 0$, then $\int_{Q_r}|f| > 0$ for $r$ large enough.
>   Also, if $x \in Q_r$, then
>
> \begin{equation}\label{eq} \frac{1}{|Q_r|} \int_{Q_r} |f| \leq \sup_{Q
>  \ni x} \frac{1}{|Q|} \int_Q |f| = Mf(x) \end{equation}
>
> Now, set  $$ t = \frac{1}{\beta} \frac{1}{|Q_r|} \int_{Q_r}|f| $$
>   where $\beta$ is **any real number greater than 1**, so that we have 
>   $$ t < \frac{1}{|Q_r|} \int_{Q_r}|f| < \beta^2 t $$ With this, we have
>   that for any $x \in Q_r$,  $$ t < \frac{1}{|Q_r|} \int_{Q_r}|f| \leq
>  Mf(x) $$ so $Q_r \subset \lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Mf(x) > t
>  \rbrace$. Therefore, $$ \int_{Q_r}|f| = |Q_r| \frac{1}{|Q_r|}
>  \int_{Q_r}|f| < |\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Mf(x) > t \rbrace|
>  \beta^2 t \leq \beta^2 \sup_{t > 0} \ t \ |\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}^n
>  : Mf(x) > t \rbrace| = \beta^2 ||Mf||_{1,w} $$ and since $Q_r$ is any
>   cube where $\int_{Q_r} |f| > 0$, then this inequality must also hold
>   for the supremum over all those cubes. That is,  $$ \|f\|_1 \leq \beta^2 \|Mf\|_{1,w} $$

I feel like there must be something wrong in here, because of the freedom I have for choosing the value of $\beta$, but I don't see where is my mistake. Can anybody tell me what I'm missing?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to  be concerned over that $\beta$. Look at it this way:

Suppose for a second that the weak-type "norm" was defined in terms of $Mf\ge t$ instead of $Mf>t$. Then we could just say this:

Let $t=\frac1{|Q|}\int_Q|f|$. Then $Mf\ge t$ on $Q$, so
$$\int_Q|f|=t|Q|\le t|\{Mf\ge t\}|,$$and we're done.

You need the $\beta$ just to jiggle this a bit to  get $Mf>t$ instead.

Comment: I see, I was just worried because I've seen similar estimates using way greater constants $C>0$ for $\|f\|_1 \leq C \|M f\|_{1,w}$ (check Stein's book "Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions", page 23, 5.2 (b)). Thank you very much!

Comment: There are different versions of "the" maximal function. For example, sometimes $Mf(x)$ is defined in terms of cubes or balls centered at $x$. The valid $C$ will be different for different versions of $Mf$; that could be the reason.